# PHP: Using a single value from one array as a key for another array?

Tags: php, html, arrays, string

I would be happy to provide more info if needed. This is the stripped-down version:

Let's say I have an array like this:

```
$field_data[0][0] = array("user_name", "table", "table[0][user_name]", "select", "200px", 0, "names");
```

And this $field_data goes until $field_data[3][15].
The structure being, of the first elem to the last: field name, table, table[index][field name], the type of input they are (text/date/select/..), size of field, index, and the name of the data from the db to display in the selector if applicable.

Then, in php:

```
$select['names'] = $db_lookup->getNamesSelect();
```

And on the front-end, I am trying to fill these out dynamically like so:

```
foreach ($field_data[$i] as &$field) {                  
            $field_name = $field[0];
            $table = $field[1];
            $table_field_name = $field[2];
            $field_type = $field[3];
            $field_size = $field[4];
            $iteration = $field[5];
            $selector = $field[6];
            $clean = ($iteration >= 0 ? $clean[$table][$iteration][$field_name] : $clean[$table][$field_name]);

            if ($field_type == 'text' || $field_type == 'date') { 
            ....
            } else if ($field_type == 'select') { 
                if($selector != null) {
                    **//This is where the problem is. This results in NULL:
                    // $select[$selector] (or $select[$field[6]])
                    // Meanwhile, $select['names'] works!**
            }
}
```

Comment: What is `$select`? Edit your question to provide a complete piece of code (a [mcve]) that anyone can copy and paste into PHP and have it run. (Note this does not mean copy and paste your entire 1500 line source file into the question!)

Comment: If `$select['names']` works and `$select[$selector]` doesn't, then the value of `$selector` is likely not what you think it is as `$ar[$var]` should work.

Comment: miken32, thank you for the link! I will do so in the future! and Kisaragi, that sounds exactly like my problem, however I am not sure what to do next. Or how to find out the type.. I guess here I go on another Googling rabbit hole

Comment: `echo $selector;`

Comment: Why wait for the future? You can edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

I messed around with it a little bit, and this works:

```
$field_data[0][1] = array("user_name", "table", "table[0][user_name]", "select", "200px", 0, "ages");
$field_data[0][0] = array("user_name", "table", "table[0][user_name]", "select", "200px", 0, "names");

$select['names'] = "Foo";

foreach ($field_data[0] as $field) {
    if (!empty($select[$field[6]])) {
        echo $select[$field[6]]."\n";
    }
}
```

I think you're just missing the second closing bracket. on $select[$field[6]] <--

Comment: Good catch, although I didn't copy-paste so I wasn't missing the second bracket in my code. I edited my post to fix that for the future. However I included that if statement and nothing would echo, even though $select[$field[6]] is not empty..